# Sanitizing passwords for password_hash()

Tags: php, security, passwords, password-hash

I was reading about the null-byte problem when using `password_hash()`. This gave me two questions:

- **Is the null-byte vulnerability still present as of PHP7?** I tried replicating it with password_hash(), but either it was fixed or I cannot replicate it. `password_verify()` returns false when characters after `\0` differ or are absent.
- **Is there any other caveat** I should be aware of when processing passwords? I do not want to sanitize them per se (the user needs to be sure that the processed password string is exactly what they sent), but I saw code like this around (again, vs null-bytes): `str_replace(chr(0), '', $input)`. Should I use this when processing passwords? Should I use something else too?

Comment: bcrypt also has a hard limit of 72 bytes, anything more is effectively truncated. If you're using PHP>=7.2 you can use the new Argon2i hash which is not subject to either of these problems.

Comment: While I'm generally against altering password input in any way, I don't suppose that deleting `NUL` bytes is the worst thing that you could do, given their effect on bcrypt. Not to mention that you would really have to screw up royal to get them in your password in the first place.

Comment: I would not even sanitize it. Just test for a NULL byte (like with strpos) and abort if true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test this with

```
$hash = password_hash("\x00 abc", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
var_dump(password_verify("\x00 foo", $hash)); // true ???
```

But when submitting a password from ie a form you receive the string '\x00 password' which will **not** interpolate like "\x00 password" would (single vs double quotes).

```
$hash = password_hash("\x00 abc", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
var_dump(password_verify('\x00 foo', $hash)); // false!
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried what you are saying, and it seems to hold true. Moreover, as @Sammitch said, with the Argon2i hash this isn't a problem either anymore. So, I will leave the passwords users submitted completely untouched.